# Obout controls in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, obout

Is anyone using the Obout controls in C# .Net?  How would you rate these controls, especially the Grid Control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was thoroughly impressed with them.  Of all the other control sets out there (infragistics, telerik) this is the only (more than) respectable one I've worked with that was 1) free! and 2) lightweight!.  The only caveat to Obout is I had trouble with merging some of these controls and some of the stock AJAX components.

Infragistics is by far my favorite (my comment about Obout being "lightweight" is in comparison with the heavy use of viewstate in some of the Infragistics controls) but it's around 1000-1500 a seat, so it can get expensive if you have a larger team.

Comment: Infragistics is a mess. I like Telerik a LOT bnetter. And they're customer service/bug fixing is very good and timely.

Comment: I used Infragistics before, its controls are so complex.

Answer (score 3):

I like obout for their lightweight'ness. Their licensing policy is very fair (pay once free updates for life) and they also give (free) educational licenses.

However, I had to use Developer Express on one of my projects and never looked back since. Very powerful and not as bloated as Infragistics.

Basically, if you decide to go obout way, you probably will not regret it.

Answer (score 2):

I like obout for their simplicity and functionality. They have pretty good documentation and samples of almost everything. And they cost a fraction of price than others (Componentart/Telerik). I am currently testing their Grid control ( after I gave up on Componentart grid for client side functionality) and find it pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I purchased the license a few years ago and have been using it ever since.  The support is pretty good and the controls are great.  I have looked at some of the other vendors (telerik, etc) but haven't moved any where because of cost transition.  The nice thing with obout is that I bought it a few years ago and they still give me free updates.  That may change inthe future, but for now, its great.  The products work as expected and they are always making updates to the software.

Answer (score 2):

This is the first time I was working with obout controls.Previously,I was working with telerik controls and so,I had a good chance of comparing these two set of controls.I would prefer Obout for its light weight and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I used their tree for a project.  Not bad for free controls.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using their Calendar control for nearly 2 years. All of a sudden it stops working on Google Chrome (Vr: 17.0.963.56 m). Even their live demos don't work, try scrolling through the months a few times and it will just hang with the error 'Uncaught TypeError: this is not a Date object.'.

I've emailed the company on two occasions regarding this issue as it has brought my site down and I'm getting customers contacting me incessantly. I'm afraid as of yet no reply!! Very frustrating!!

It's really a shame because the tool is otherwise excellent...If they could at least acknowledge the fault and assure me they are working on a solution that would be something, but to be left in the dark shows a complete lack of basic customer service etiquette.